# Warnings and unexpected behavior when importing ydata-profiling python package

Tags: conda, virtualenv, version, python-packaging

When importing the `ydata-profiling` python package I am presented with a warning message, then unexpected behavior when I try to check the `__version__` attribute

All of the following is being done in the terminal on a MacBook Pro running Ventura 13.4.1. If any additional information would be helpful, please let me know. I'm not an expert, so please be patient with me.

I followed the instructions found [here](https://ydata-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/getting_started/installation.html) to install the `ydata-profiling` package. I did have to modify the first line, slightly: The instructions say to use `conda env create -n ydata-profiling` whereas I used `conda create -n ydata-profiling`. (This is based on the instructions in [conda docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#id13))

Here is what I ran:

```
conda create -n ydata-profiling
conda activate ydata-profiling
conda install -c conda-forge ydata-profiling
```

Here was the output:

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda create -n ydata-profiling
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/ydata-profiling



Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate ydata-profiling
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda activate ydata-profiling
(ydata-profiling) user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda install -c conda-forge ydata-profiling
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/ydata-profiling

  added / updated specs:
    - ydata-profiling


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    brotli-python-1.0.9        |  py311ha397e9f_9         317 KB  conda-forge
    contourpy-1.1.0            |  py311he4fd1f5_0         220 KB  conda-forge
    llvmlite-0.40.1            |  py311hea943cd_0         325 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-2.1.3           |  py311heffc1b2_0          26 KB  conda-forge
    matplotlib-base-3.7.2      |  py311h3bc9839_0         7.4 MB  conda-forge
    numba-0.57.1               |  py311hbf3c4e2_0         5.3 MB  conda-forge
    pandas-2.0.3               |  py311h9e438b8_1        13.5 MB  conda-forge
    pillow-10.0.0              |  py311h095fde6_0        43.8 MB  conda-forge
    pyyaml-6.0                 |  py311he2be06e_5         189 KB  conda-forge
    scipy-1.10.1               |  py311h93d07a4_3        14.0 MB  conda-forge
    urllib3-2.0.4              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          96 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        85.1 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  attrs              conda-forge/noarch::attrs-23.1.0-pyh71513ae_1
  brotli             conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotli-1.0.9-h1a8c8d9_9
  brotli-bin         conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotli-bin-1.0.9-h1a8c8d9_9
  brotli-python      conda-forge/osx-arm64::brotli-python-1.0.9-py311ha397e9f_9
  bzip2              conda-forge/osx-arm64::bzip2-1.0.8-h3422bc3_4
  ca-certificates    conda-forge/osx-arm64::ca-certificates-2023.7.22-hf0a4a13_0
  certifi            conda-forge/noarch::certifi-2023.7.22-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  charset-normalizer conda-forge/noarch::charset-normalizer-3.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  colorama           conda-forge/noarch::colorama-0.4.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  contourpy          conda-forge/osx-arm64::contourpy-1.1.0-py311he4fd1f5_0
  cycler             conda-forge/noarch::cycler-0.11.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  dacite             conda-forge/noarch::dacite-1.8.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  dataclasses        conda-forge/noarch::dataclasses-0.8-pyhc8e2a94_3
  fonttools          conda-forge/osx-arm64::fonttools-4.42.0-py311heffc1b2_0
  freetype           conda-forge/osx-arm64::freetype-2.12.1-hd633e50_1
  htmlmin            conda-forge/noarch::htmlmin-0.1.12-py_1
  idna               conda-forge/noarch::idna-3.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  imagehash          conda-forge/noarch::imagehash-4.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  jinja2             conda-forge/noarch::jinja2-3.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  joblib             conda-forge/noarch::joblib-1.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  kiwisolver         conda-forge/osx-arm64::kiwisolver-1.4.4-py311hd6ee22a_1
  lcms2              conda-forge/osx-arm64::lcms2-2.15-hd835a16_1
  lerc               conda-forge/osx-arm64::lerc-4.0.0-h9a09cb3_0
  libblas            conda-forge/osx-arm64::libblas-3.9.0-17_osxarm64_openblas
  libbrotlicommon    conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlicommon-1.0.9-h1a8c8d9_9
  libbrotlidec       conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlidec-1.0.9-h1a8c8d9_9
  libbrotlienc       conda-forge/osx-arm64::libbrotlienc-1.0.9-h1a8c8d9_9
  libcblas           conda-forge/osx-arm64::libcblas-3.9.0-17_osxarm64_openblas
  libcxx             conda-forge/osx-arm64::libcxx-16.0.6-h4653b0c_0
  libdeflate         conda-forge/osx-arm64::libdeflate-1.18-h1a8c8d9_0
  libexpat           conda-forge/osx-arm64::libexpat-2.5.0-hb7217d7_1
  libffi             conda-forge/osx-arm64::libffi-3.4.2-h3422bc3_5
  libgfortran        conda-forge/osx-arm64::libgfortran-5.0.0-12_3_0_hd922786_1
  libgfortran5       conda-forge/osx-arm64::libgfortran5-12.3.0-ha3a6a3e_1
  libjpeg-turbo      conda-forge/osx-arm64::libjpeg-turbo-2.1.5.1-h1a8c8d9_0
  liblapack          conda-forge/osx-arm64::liblapack-3.9.0-17_osxarm64_openblas
  libllvm14          conda-forge/osx-arm64::libllvm14-14.0.6-hd1a9a77_4
  libopenblas        conda-forge/osx-arm64::libopenblas-0.3.23-openmp_hc731615_0
  libpng             conda-forge/osx-arm64::libpng-1.6.39-h76d750c_0
  libsqlite          conda-forge/osx-arm64::libsqlite-3.42.0-hb31c410_0
  libtiff            conda-forge/osx-arm64::libtiff-4.5.1-h23a1a89_0
  libwebp-base       conda-forge/osx-arm64::libwebp-base-1.3.1-hb547adb_0
  libxcb             conda-forge/osx-arm64::libxcb-1.15-hf346824_0
  libzlib            conda-forge/osx-arm64::libzlib-1.2.13-h53f4e23_5
  llvm-openmp        conda-forge/osx-arm64::llvm-openmp-16.0.6-h1c12783_0
  llvmlite           conda-forge/osx-arm64::llvmlite-0.40.1-py311hea943cd_0
  markupsafe         conda-forge/osx-arm64::markupsafe-2.1.3-py311heffc1b2_0
  matplotlib-base    conda-forge/osx-arm64::matplotlib-base-3.7.2-py311h3bc9839_0
  multimethod        conda-forge/noarch::multimethod-1.4-py_0
  munkres            conda-forge/noarch::munkres-1.1.4-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  ncurses            conda-forge/osx-arm64::ncurses-6.4-h7ea286d_0
  networkx           conda-forge/noarch::networkx-3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  numba              conda-forge/osx-arm64::numba-0.57.1-py311hbf3c4e2_0
  numpy              conda-forge/osx-arm64::numpy-1.23.5-py311ha92fb03_0
  openjpeg           conda-forge/osx-arm64::openjpeg-2.5.0-hbc2ba62_2
  openssl            conda-forge/osx-arm64::openssl-3.1.2-h53f4e23_0
  packaging          conda-forge/noarch::packaging-23.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pandas             conda-forge/osx-arm64::pandas-2.0.3-py311h9e438b8_1
  patsy              conda-forge/noarch::patsy-0.5.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  phik               conda-forge/noarch::phik-0.11.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pillow             conda-forge/osx-arm64::pillow-10.0.0-py311h095fde6_0
  pip                conda-forge/noarch::pip-23.2.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  platformdirs       conda-forge/noarch::platformdirs-3.10.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pooch              conda-forge/noarch::pooch-1.7.0-pyha770c72_3
  pthread-stubs      conda-forge/osx-arm64::pthread-stubs-0.4-h27ca646_1001
  pydantic           conda-forge/osx-arm64::pydantic-1.10.12-py311heffc1b2_1
  pyparsing          conda-forge/noarch::pyparsing-3.0.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pysocks            conda-forge/noarch::pysocks-1.7.1-pyha2e5f31_6
  python             conda-forge/osx-arm64::python-3.11.4-h47c9636_0_cpython
  python-dateutil    conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python-tzdata      conda-forge/noarch::python-tzdata-2023.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/osx-arm64::python_abi-3.11-3_cp311
  pytz               conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2023.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pywavelets         conda-forge/osx-arm64::pywavelets-1.4.1-py311h4add359_0
  pyyaml             conda-forge/osx-arm64::pyyaml-6.0-py311he2be06e_5
  readline           conda-forge/osx-arm64::readline-8.2-h92ec313_1
  requests           conda-forge/noarch::requests-2.31.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  scipy              conda-forge/osx-arm64::scipy-1.10.1-py311h93d07a4_3
  seaborn            conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-0.12.2-hd8ed1ab_0
  seaborn-base       conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-base-0.12.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  setuptools         conda-forge/noarch::setuptools-68.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  six                conda-forge/noarch::six-1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0
  statsmodels        conda-forge/osx-arm64::statsmodels-0.14.0-py311hb49d859_1
  tangled-up-in-uni~ conda-forge/noarch::tangled-up-in-unicode-0.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  tk                 conda-forge/osx-arm64::tk-8.6.12-he1e0b03_0
  tqdm               conda-forge/noarch::tqdm-4.65.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  typeguard          conda-forge/noarch::typeguard-2.13.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  typing-extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing-extensions-4.7.1-hd8ed1ab_0
  typing_extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-4.7.1-pyha770c72_0
  tzdata             conda-forge/noarch::tzdata-2023c-h71feb2d_0
  urllib3            conda-forge/noarch::urllib3-2.0.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  visions            conda-forge/noarch::visions-0.7.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  wheel              conda-forge/noarch::wheel-0.41.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  wordcloud          conda-forge/osx-arm64::wordcloud-1.9.2-py311heffc1b2_1
  xorg-libxau        conda-forge/osx-arm64::xorg-libxau-1.0.11-hb547adb_0
  xorg-libxdmcp      conda-forge/osx-arm64::xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h27ca646_0
  xz                 conda-forge/osx-arm64::xz-5.2.6-h57fd34a_0
  yaml               conda-forge/osx-arm64::yaml-0.2.5-h3422bc3_2
  ydata-profiling    conda-forge/noarch::ydata-profiling-4.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  zstd               conda-forge/osx-arm64::zstd-1.5.2-h4f39d0f_7


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(ydata-profiling) user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Then, I used `python3` to start python and tried to import ydata-profiling and check the version. Here is the result:

```
(ydata-profiling) user@Users-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3
Python 3.11.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 10 2023, 18:08:41) [Clang 15.0.7 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ydata_profiling
/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/ydata-profiling/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/decorators.py:262: NumbaDeprecationWarning: numba.generated_jit is deprecated. Please see the documentation at: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-generated-jit for more information and advice on a suitable replacement.
  warnings.warn(msg, NumbaDeprecationWarning)
/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/ydata-profiling/lib/python3.11/site-packages/visions/backends/shared/nan_handling.py:50: NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
  @nb.jit
>>> ydata_profiling.__version__
'0.0.dev0'
>>>
```

So, there are a couple of things going on that I would like to better understand (and fix, if possible)

1. The deprecation warnings are annoying, I don't know whether they indicate that I've set something up incorrectly, or if I can safely ignore them forever.
2. The incorrect output of `ydata_profiling.__version__` is more troubling. That really seems like it should work if everything is installed correctly, and I'm worried its a symptom of something else being set up incorrectly.